# Nginx Bad Gatway error happened when use it as reverse proxy to Grafana

Tags: nginx, unix, grafana

I'm running Nginx on port 3000 and it's running fine and running Grafana on port 8080 and it's running fine.
when I use Nginx as a reverse proxy for Grafana I got bad Gatway below is nginx configuration and the error log

Nginx Configuration File:

```
server {
listen 3000 ssl;
#root /usr/share/nginx/html;
#index index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate /etc/grafana/ELK4.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/grafana/ELK4.key;

location / {
proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_grafana.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error_grafana.log;
}

location /api/live {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection “Upgrade”;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/;
}
}
```

Error.log File:
connect() failed (111 connection refused) while connecting to upstream client

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/;
```

To:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marcelo but it's not working I got the below error  "client sent an HTTP request to HTTPS server "

Comment: So you're using "protocol = https" in Grafana configuration, right? Try to use the default "3000" Grafana port (http_port = 3000) instead of "8080".